# How to implement Soap Faults in Java webservices?

Tags: java, vb.net, web-services, apache-axis, soapfault

Am pretty new to web services and have been trying to implement Soap Faults. I used Apache Axis2 to generate webservice in the following manner.

```
public interface XYZ{
public String myMethod(User[] user)
}
```

Here I have created a User class with some variables so that I can generate User object at .Net environment to pass User[] of objects.

```
Public class Webservice implements XYZ
{
Public String myMethod(User[] user){
//My implementation
}
}
```

Now, I created a dynamic project using Eclipse and with the help of Axis2 plugin I created webservice for my "Webservice" class which generates wsdl file. I deployed the webcontent in the Tomcat folder and able to access the WSDL file in the .Net environment. I am able to pass array of objects (User[]) from .Net to Java and able to do my task. Now, I need to implement Soap Faults in Java which I am not sure how to implement.

Can anyone help me with an example or tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to Google for something like "jax-ws faults".  For example:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-jaxws-faults/index.html

You can also implement an error handler, as discussed under "Using handlers in JAX-WS Web services" here:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html#BottomUpService

Answer (score 1):

Most frameworks will trigger a SOAP fault when you throw an Exception in the method implementing your operation. That will not give you much control on the SOAP fault content though.

See [here](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Exceptions) for some details on Axis

Answer (score 1):

Generally, You don't need any specific coding for implementing SOAP fault.. Whenever there is any exception thrown by the method (here `myMethod` in your example.), axis will automatically generate SOAPFault element in the resulting response. The exception is actually wrapped into `AxisFault` exception and sent to the client.

See here a [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191826/web-service-throwing-exception-using-axis2-java).